# Cadaver with Kerberos: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: kerberos, webdav

How to make [Cadaver](http://www.webdav.org/cadaver/) connect to a WebDAV server that uses [Kerberos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29) authentication?

Usually `cadaver http://localhost:8080/alfresco/webdav` works, I can browse files, but on a network with Kerberos I get:

```
Could not open collection:
401 Unauthorized
```

Even though I have logged in with `kinit` successfully and have a valid ticket.

I can see that Kerberos support has been implemented in Cadaver in [2005](http://www.webdav.org/cadaver/). Is there a special syntax to use? No info in the `man`.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled upon this. This is not Cadaver's fault. It is using libneon as transport. First, you must compile neon with GSS-API support + you have to apply a patch to support SPNEGO, it's passing naked Kerberos tickets only.

Here's the discussion: http://lists.manyfish.co.uk/pipermail/neon/2012-June/001475.html

Here's the verified patch: http://lists.manyfish.co.uk/pipermail/neon/2012-July/001494.html

Comment: Interesting! Do you have any link to the procedure or the patch?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul, see edit.

Comment: Please report back,  I am inclined to try that too.

Comment: I was able to compile cadaver with neon 0.29.7-dev but when I run cadaver, it fails with a segfault. From the core dump I do see this:

OPTIONS /files/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: cadaver/0.23.3 neon/0.29.7-dev
Keep-Alive:
Connection: TE, Keep-Alive
TE: trailers
Host: ...:18080
Authorization: Negotiate YIIQLwYGKwYBBQ...

So, someone has to fix cadaver with neon first.

I know that neon works because I have verifed it in tandem with Subversion.